# R Apply - need to retrieve values in previous row

Tags: r, apply

I am modeling the charge state of a battery over time. The best (only) working solution I have found is with a for-loop. I want to use "apply" or another solution if possible as this for-loop is slowing my code down considerably.

'df' is my data frame. 'df$batteryBeginCharge' is the beginning charge of the battery in each time step (row). 'df$Charge.Discharge' is the amount of charge entering or leaving the battery in each time step.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  {
    if(i!=1) df$batteryBeginCharge[i] <<- df$batteryBeginCharge[i-1] + df$Charge.Discharge[i-1]

    df$Charge.Discharge[i] <<- df$electricDemand[i] - df$electricSupply[i] #function of other columns of df, all in row 'i'
  }
```

This seems like a perfect situation to use the "apply" family, but I cannot find a way to retrieve values of previous rows within "apply", which I need for my  'df$batteryBeginCharge' parameter.

I don't think I can use vectorization on 'df$batteryBeginCharge' and 'df$Charge.Discharge' separately, as they are obviously linked on a row-by-row basis.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could have several options here e.g. using apply, or dplyr or data.table. Here the example using data.table. Is this what you want?

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(batteryBeginCharge = c(10,25,40), Charge.Discharge = c(20,30,50))
df[ , x := shift(batteryBeginCharge, 1L, type="lag")  + shift(Charge.Discharge, 1L, type="lag")]
```

Note that this part of the code is missing (`df$Charge.Discharge[i] <<-` ), hence your example can't not be reproduced completely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some detail to the "df$Charge.Discharge[i] <<-" portion to give you an idea of what is happening there. Is there a way I can accomplish this using apply or dplyr? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I think this answer does not address a key feature of the problem. The battery beginning charge, and discharge for each row need to be evaluated one after the other within each row.